# Flash drive with ISO not seen in BIOS or not booting at all

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation, uefi, bios

I've got a problem. I cannot install any OS and I don't know why. I as usually copied artix linux iso to my flash drive to install it on server. Then in BIOS settings, drive didn't appear till I changed boot type to legacy. But when I try to boot from disk I got message that I have no bootable device. I tried to do the same with Manjaro, mark the volume as bootable, take another usb drive, even tried to boot from laptop, but nothing gave me effect. I had a problem with proxmox before, I don't know if it the same, but the kernel didn't load up on server, so I booted proxmox on laptop and installed it on hard drive via usb adapter, but now I am not able to do even that. Also, I have artix installed on my laptop, but somehow it doesn't detect any usb bootable drives in BIOS like before, only as external storage.
P. S. Sorry for my bad english, I tried my best:)

Comment: can you tell us what it means to "copy artix linux iso to my flash drive"? Because, usually, that's *not* how you make bootable USB drives, assuming you just copied the .iso *file* onto the stick's file system.

Comment: I meant writing image via dd to volume, like "dd if=some.iso of=/dev/sdaX"

Comment: Well, it was very stupid, it turns out that I misunderstood the work of this program and in principle what iso images are, so I forgot that it is necessary to specify the whole disk and not the partition. Thank you!

Comment: ironically, copying the iso to the filesystem on the usb works fine if you first install ventoy.

Answer (score 0):

I should specify not the partition, but the whole disk

Comment: glad you got it to work!